# Adaptive Canny Edge Detection Algorithm

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I am trying to implement Canny Algorithm using python from scratch.

I am following the steps

1. Bilateral Filtering the image
2. Gradient calculation using First Derivative of Gaussian oriented in 4 different directions

`def deroGauss(w=5,s=1,angle=0):`

```
    wlim = (w-1)/2
    y,x = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-wlim,wlim+1),np.arange(-wlim,wlim+1))
    G = np.exp(-np.sum((np.square(x),np.square(y)),axis=0)/(2*np.float64(s)**2))
    G = G/np.sum(G)
    dGdx = -np.multiply(x,G)/np.float64(s)**2
    dGdy = -np.multiply(y,G)/np.float64(s)**2

    angle = angle*math.pi/180 #converting to radians

    dog = math.cos(angle)*dGdx + math.sin(angle)*dGdy

    return dog
```

3. Non max suppression in all the 4 gradient image

`def nonmaxsup(I,gradang):`

```
    dim = I.shape
    Inms = np.zeros(dim)
    weak = np.zeros(dim)    
    strong = np.zeros(dim)
    final = np.zeros(dim)
    xshift = int(np.round(math.cos(gradang*np.pi/180)))
    yshift = int(np.round(math.sin(gradang*np.pi/180)))
    Ipad = np.pad(I,(1,),'constant',constant_values = (0,0))
    for r in xrange(1,dim[0]+1):
        for c in xrange(1,dim[1]+1):
            maggrad = [Ipad[r-xshift,c-yshift],Ipad[r,c],Ipad[r+xshift,c+yshift]]
            if Ipad[r,c] == np.max(maggrad):
                Inms[r-1,c-1] = Ipad[r,c]
    return Inms
```

4. Double Thresholding and Hysteresis: Now here the real problem comes.

I am using Otsu's method toe calculate the thresholds.

Should I use the grayscale image or the Gradient images to calculate the threshold?

Because in the gradient Image the pixel intensity values are getting reduced to a very low value after bilateral filtering and then after convolving with Derivative of Gaussian it is reduced further. For example :: 28, 15

Threshold calculated using the grayscale is much above the threshold calculated using the gradient image.

Also If I use the grayscale or even the gradient images to calculate the thresholds the resultant image is not good enough and does not contain all the edges.

So practically, I have nothing left to apply Hysteresis on.

I have tried

`img_edge = img_edge*255/np.max(img_edge)`

to scale up the values but the result remains the same

But if I use the same thresholds with `cv2.Canny` the result is very good.

What actually can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the Otsu threshold from the original image doesn't make sense, it is completely unrelated to the gradient intensities.

Otsu from the gradient intensities is not perfect because the statistical distributions of noise and edges are skewed and overlap a lot.

You can try some small multiple of Otsu or some small multiple of the average. But in no case will you get perfect results by simple or hysteresis thresholding. Edge detection is an ill-posed problem.

Comment: But the `cv2.Canny` function takes two inputs, the lower and the upper threshold calculated from the grayscale image. How does it give so good output?

Comment: But there must be some way by which the right threshold value can be obtained from the low pixel values of the gradient image. In my case even if I apply otsu's method to the gradient image it returns a threshold value which is not suitable for the purpose but if I divide it by 3 or 4 and then set it as upper threshold, it works better.

Comment: @Siladittya: exacty like I said.

Comment: But the problem is, although I get edges, they are not thinned like in the `cv2.Canny`. There are small edge like things extending out in a direction orthogonal to the edges. The edges are not totally perfect. A post-processing step of non-max suppression doesn't help. Also, hysteresis is of no use in this case. The images before and after hysteresis are the same.